# Android openssl.cnf location

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface

I need to load openssl.cnf file in openssl native library compiled for Android. I successfully compiled openssl libary in Android NDK, and there are three so files for modules: libcrypto, libssl and also, libapps which needs openssl.cnf file to run some commands. What I did is that I copied openssl.cnf file to Application's cache directory and edited **openssl/include/opensslconf.h** to point to the openssl.cnf file in cache directory:

```
#define OPENSSLDIR "/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache"
```

It works fine, but as the path of cache folder varies in different devices and ROMs, I should use some better way than this one. How to properly point to openssl.cnf file in opensslconf.h file? Should I pass the path of cache directory (or any directory that native libs could find it's path) to native lib and how to do this?